# No route found for "GET /test_project/web/app_dev.php/calculator/20"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm newbie in Symfony, so sorry if my question is really obvious.
I'm using Symfony 3.4.2.

My file **app/config/routing.yml**:

```
app:
path: /calculator/{age}
defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Calculator:index}
```

And the file **src/AppBundle/Controller/CalculatorController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($age)
    {
        $currentYear = date ('Y');
        return new Response('<html><body>Current year: ' . $currentYear . '<br/>Year of birth: ' . ($currentYear - $age) . '</body></html>');
     }
}
```

I've just fixed a bug encountered in 3.4.2: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25523

But now, when I try to run my app by http://localhost:8000/test_project/web/app_dev.php/calculator/20

I get No route found for "GET /test_project/web/app_dev.php/calculator/20"

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /test_project/web/app_dev.php/calculator/20"" at
>   D:\netbeans-projects\symfony3\test-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php
>   line 139

Comment: All of us was a noob so no worries. Did you start your server with php bin/console server:run (do this command in the project directory)

Comment: And if you did then test_project should probably not be in the url

Comment: Tell us more about your web server and its configuration.

Comment: I had already started the app as you said Smaine. That's not the problem. Also I've  tried without test_project in the url but it also doesn't work

Comment: Wolen, please tell me what you need to know exactly

Comment: SOLVED! Instead of 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
I changed it into:
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

And also the url: http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/calculator/20

Comment: @Elena please add it as a response an then validate it.

Comment: It's run by a friend, so full disclosure, but KnpUniversity has pretty great Symfony tutorials.